# Is storing in a variable the result of a fonction a most powerful way to code an if structures in WordPress?

Tags: functions, performance

In the footer-menus-widgets.php template, from Twenty Twenty theme (by Automatic), we can find a way to code a template and call functions that uses variables to store the result of functions like `has_nav_menu()` or `is_active_sidebar()` and then use it later in the template in an if structure `if ( $has_footer_menu)` instead of using directly the function itself. Here is the code (i've shortened it) :

```
<?php
/**
 * Displays the menus and widgets at the end of the main element.
 */

$has_footer_menu = has_nav_menu( 'footer' );
$has_social_menu = has_nav_menu( 'social' );
$has_sidebar_1 = is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' );
$has_sidebar_2 = is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' );

if ( $has_footer_menu || $has_social_menu || $has_sidebar_1 || $has_sidebar_2 ) {
    ?>

    <div>
        <?php if ( $has_footer_menu || $has_social_menu ) { ?>
            <div class="footer-top">

                <?php if ( $has_footer_menu ) { ?>
                    <nav role="navigation">
                        <!-- some code… -->
                    </nav><!-- .site-nav -->
                <?php } ?>

                <?php if ( $has_social_menu ) { ?>
                    <nav role="navigation">
                        <!-- some code… -->
                    </nav><!-- .footer-social-wrapper -->
                <?php } ?>

            </div><!-- .footer-top -->

        <?php } ?>

        <?php if ( $has_sidebar_1 || $has_sidebar_2 ) { ?>
            <aside>

                <div>

                    <?php if ( $has_sidebar_1 ) { ?>

                        <div>
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
                        </div>

                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if ( $has_sidebar_2 ) { ?>

                        <div>
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ); ?>
                        </div>

                    <?php } ?>

                </div><!-- .footer-widgets-wrapper -->

            </aside><!-- .footer-widgets-outer-wrapper -->
        <?php } ?>

    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

But in Twenty Seventeen footer-widgets.php template file, we only find the functions :

```
<?php
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) ||
    is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' ) ) :
    ?>

    <aside class="widget-area" role="complementary" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Footer', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?>">
        <?php
        if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) ) {
            ?>
            <div class="widget-column footer-widget-1">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ); ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' ) ) {
            ?>
            <div class="widget-column footer-widget-2">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' ); ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </aside><!-- .widget-area -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

My question is : why are they coded differently ? Does the Twenty Twenty template increase the performance of the code (decreasing the resources consumed, the page speed) ? Meaning : is it a better way of coding to store the result of a function like `has_nav_menu()` in a variable like in Twenty Twenty? Or is it only about maintainability and readability of code ?

Comment: At first glance is_active_sidebar is definitely cached, i.e. you can repeatedly call it with the same query and it will only hit the database once, so Twenty Seventeen is efficient enough. I'm less sure how get_theme_mod() works, which is what has_nav_menu() calls, so I'd guess that that's not necessarily cached so in Twenty Twenty they introduced a variable to store that result in case it's not cheaply repeatable and then applied the same pattern to is_active_sidebar too. But hopefully someone who knows get_theme_mod() better can give a definitive answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rup : do you know if it exists a WordPress documentation on this topic ?